# How to enable custom TRACE macro for specific files only?

Tags: c, embedded

I wrote the following trace macro in a file named "debug.h".

```
#define TRACE(x)     \
    printf(          \
        "%s(%d): ",  \
        __FILE__,    \
        __LINE__     \
        );           \
                     \
  printf(x);
```

In debug I'd like to enable the macro only for certain files since resources are limited on the platform that I'm using. I don't want to completely remove the TRACE calls from the files. Just disable them.

Is there a clean way to do this in C using the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `debug.h`:

```
#if TRACE_ENABLE
#define TRACE(x)     \
    printf(          \
        "%s(%d): ",  \
        __FILE__,    \
        __LINE__     \
        );           \
                     \
  printf(x);
#else
#define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

Then, in your source files where you don't want trace:

```
#define TRACE_ENABLE 0
#include "debug.h"
```

or just:

```
#include "debug.h"
```

In source files to enable trace:

```
#define TRACE_ENABLE 1
#include "debug.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

A trick I've used somtimes is the use of a bit mask to enable a subset of the files whete the TRACE is used:
File1.c:

```
#if TRACE_MASK & 0x01
#define TRACE(x) ...
#endif
```

File2.c:

```
#if TRACE_MASK & 0x02
#define TRACE(x) ...
#endif
```

...
Then you can define your TRACE_MASK macro in the preprocessing options: /DTRACE_MASK=0x03 to enable the trace on both File1.c and File2.c
The only problem is that there is a limited numner of bits... (but you can use more than one macro: TRACE_MASK1, TRACE_MASK2...)
Bye

EDIT: of course you can write tdefinition once in a file "trace.h", and just redefine the mask in each source:

File trace.h:

```
#if TRACE_MASK & TRACE_CURRENT
#define TRACE(x) ...
#else
#define TRACE(x) do {} while(0)
#endif
```

File1.c:

```
#define TRACE_CURRENT 0x01
#include "trace.h"
```

File2.c:

```
#define TRACE_CURRENT 0x02
#include "trace.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

While both answers seems good to me, I think Giuseppe's answer is more useful most of the time since if you use this macro many times in a file, and you want to switch debug on/off for complete files, pmg's method is exhausting.
The important thing is to not forget adding the else statement: `#else TRACE(X);` if you want to edit it in the specific file and not in header, use:

```
#ifdef TRACE
#undef TRACE
#endif
#define TRACE(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
#define TRACE(x, y) do if (y) {/*your prints*/} while (0)
```

and also

```
#define TRACE_ENABLE 1
```

or

```
#define TRACE_ENABLE 0
```

at the top of your sources.

Then replace the TRACE invocations with

```
TRACE(foo, TRACE_ENABLE);
```